# Is there any query to retrieve the data present in list firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve only that post where **postCategory** matches the user interest.
How can I achieve this type of query. Any Help??
Below is my json file of database..

```
"Posts" : {
"-MAKobGjdhMfJFwZ1kol" : {
  "postCategory" : "Animals",
  "postDesc" : "still",
  "postImage" : "Image Link",
  "postPersonName" : "Name",
  "postPersonUid" : "CLQA22uZpLS1ErIrnoBTrC3xqBw2",
  "postTitle" : "ek"
},
 "Users" : {
 "CLQA22uZpLS1ErIrnoBTrC3xqBw2" : {
   "email" : "email",
   "interest" : {
    "-MA14zFcNfs1JAjux129" : {
      "name" : "Developer"
    },
    "-MA14zFgzhL-MOBB7D6h" : {
      "name" : "Shopping"
    }
  },
   "name" : "Name",
   "uid" : "CLQA22uZpLS1ErIrnoBTrC3xqBw2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `firebase database` you cannot have such queries.
You should use `Firestore (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)` for such advanced queries.

[firestore/query-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

[firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)

Answer (score 0):

To get all posts with `postCategory` equal to `Animals`, you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
Query query = ref.orderBy("postCategory").equalTo("Animals");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, postSnapshot.getKey()+": "+postSnapshot.child("postTitle").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve posts for multiple categories, you'll have to perform a separate query for each of those and merge the results on your client.

---

I'd also recommend changing how you store the categories for a user. The idiomatic way is:

```
"Users" : {
 "CLQA22uZpLS1ErIrnoBTrC3xqBw2" : {
   "email" : "email",
   "interest" : {
      "Developer": true,
      "Shopping": true
    }
  },
```

The reasons this is more common is that it automatically ensures that each value can occur only once in the `interest` object, since property names are by definition unique.